# How can I only read items that fall within a date range in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having trouble working out the correct way of creating a date range that runs from the 26th of the month to the 21st of the following month in Angular JS. What I want to do is sort a list out to only show items in a table that have been modified or created within that date range. However, that date range must always be for that period every month.

So for instance, since it is the 8th of October now, it needs to show the period between the 26th of September to the 21st of October. Then later on, after the 26th of October, it then starts over to show records only from the 26th of October to the 21st of November.

Would you have any suggestions as to the correct way of doing a dynamic date range like this?

Regards

Comment: Is it the coding part or logic where u stuck?

Comment: I have the logic I think in mind. You take the current date, check it in an if statement that it falls either before the 21st or after the 26th of the current month. Then if it is after the 26th of the current month set the end date as the 21st of the following month and start  date as the 26th of current month. If it is before the 21st then set the end date as the 21st of the current month and set the start date as the 26th of the previous month. The problem is how to code that kind of logic in Angular where the date is filtered outside of a controller in the view.

Comment: you are getting all data from your server  and sort it on with angular or do you want to create a call to get only those days?

Comment: I am getting all data from server. Basically, I want to create a filter that can be activated to only show current period or deactivated to show everything.

Comment: I dont have a complete answer. But do look into angular moment which is simply the best library for stuffs related to date manipulation in javascript. https://github.com/urish/angular-moment